# PHP Curl - SSL peer had some unspecified issue with the certificate it received

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

This is the request I'm sending with my PHP code-

```
$url = 'https://mywebserviceurl.com';
$method='GET';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 'TRUE');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__.'/print_ca_ca.cer');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, __DIR__.'/print_ca_cert.cer');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, __DIR__.'/print_ca_key_decr.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'somepassword');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response    = curl_exec($ch);
    $resp = json_encode($response);
    $this->setErrorCodeMessage('401', 'Response-> '.$resp); //get a False here

    $error = curl_error($ch);
    $this->setErrorCodeMessage('401', 'Error-> '.$error); //get Error here

    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($status_code == '200' && !empty($response)) {
            $this->setErrorCodeMessage('401', 'Inside 200 OK..');
    }
```

The Error that I see on my Error Logs is-

*SSL peer had some unspecified issue with the certificate it received.*

When I do **php -a** and try to run the request as is on the shell, along with the above error line I also get the following-

*NSS error -12224 (SSL_ERROR_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN_ALERT)*

I originally had a p12 file and got a ca chain(.cer file), ssl cert(.cer file) and key files(.pem file) from it using the openssl commands, and I'm using these files with the Curl request.
At this point I've tried everything; using pem,crt,cer files, setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to different values and also tried a POST request, but i keep getting *SSL peer had some unspecified issue with the certificate it received.*

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions?

PS- I've used the original P12 file and its password on Postman and have been able to send both GET/POST requests without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you receive is due to the server not accepting your client certificate (the `print_ca_cert.cer`). `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` etc will not help since these option are about verifying the server certificate by the client.

It is unclear what the server does not like with your client certificate since it is unknown what the requirements are for this certificate and what's actually in the files you've received. It might be that the `print_ca_ca.cer` is not the CA for the server certificate which you configure with `CURLOPT_CAINFO` but that it is an intermediate CA you need to send together with your client certificate. In this case you need to append your `print_ca_ca.cer` to your `print_ca_cert.cer`. But again, these are just speculations since nothing is known about the contents of these files.

Comment: I got it to work. So there was nothing in the PHP/Curl code that was blocking it, it was the server. There was also a ca cert bundle on the server that I did not know about, and the ca cert that i use needed to be chained in there. I did that and it allowed the curl request without any issues. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @manishk: To translate your description from purely anecdotal ("did something and it worked" - without explanation why) to a more systematic one: you've used a client certificate but you did not send the chain certificates with it (your `print_ca_ca.cer`). You've "fixed" this by making the chain certificates trusted at the server so that the client does not need to send this instead of letting the client send the chain certificates as I explicitly proposed in my answer.

Comment: When did I say otherwise? You answer definitely pointed me in the right direction.